# How to implement after_stat(ymax) with count expression in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, stat

I would like to add n numbers to each ggplot box plots with the italic(n) = #.

I have tried `expression` and `bquote` for label but did not work. Any suggestion?

```
stat_summary(fun = median, fun.max = length,geom = "text", aes(label = expression(paste(~italic(n)," = ", after_stat(ymax) )) ), vjust = -5)
```

on title,

`ggtitle(bquote(paste("POLAR - HR | ", ~italic(n), " = ", .(sum(df.summ$file.len)) )))`

works well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether there is an option to make expression work with `after_stat`. But one option would be to create your label as a character string and use `parse=TRUE` in `geom_text`.

Minimal reprex based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = median, fun.max = length,
    geom = "text",
    aes(
      label = after_stat(paste0("italic(n) == ", ymax))
    ), vjust = .5, parse = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

Comment: For the size of stat labels, we can use the following:

`stat_summary(
    fun = median, fun.max = length,
    geom = "text",
    fontface = "bold",
    size = 3.5,
    aes(
      label = after_stat(paste0("italic(n) == ", ymax))
    ), vjust = -5, parse = TRUE
  )+`